# Develop for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to develop (webparts etc.), using Visual studio 2010, for Sharepoint 2010 without having it installed on the developer machine(virtual or direct in Windows7)? E.g developing against a shared server or without beeing connected to a server at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use the SharePoint development tools in Visual Studio 2010 without having SharePoint installed locally.

If you try to do so, you will see this error message:

[SharePoint not installed locally http://msmvps.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/350x0/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/windsor/8422.SharePointNotInstalled.png](http://msmvps.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/350x0/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/windsor/8422.SharePointNotInstalled.png)

Comment: Does this also mean I require a 64bit OS to develop on?

Comment: Yes, SharePoint 2010 will only run on a 64bit OS

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not. You will see an error message that Rob's shared. The easiest way is using a shared test server, if you don't want to install virtual machine. But for each way, you need a license to use Sharepoint Server.